# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined at AdminProductsComponent.onclickfetch()

Tags: angular

Hey guys I am new to Angular and this is my first project that i am making.

So, my issue is that i am storing my data on cloud firestore  and then fetching it from there.So, when i at the beginning try to access the data from cloud firestore (the data already exists in database) i am receiving this error

**Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at AdminProductsComponent.push../src/app/admin/admin-products/admin-products.component.ts.AdminProductsComponent.onclickfetch**

but if at beginning i first add atleast one data into cloud firestore and then if i fetch it from there i am not receiving this error

Here below is the code..

html component

```
<button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" (click)="onclickfetch()" mdbWavesEffect>Fetch Products</button>
```

service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 
{AngularFirestoreDocument,AngularFirestore,AngularFirestoreCollection} 
from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Item } from '../items';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemsService {
private itemscollection:AngularFirestoreCollection<any[]>
datacollection:AngularFirestoreCollection<any[]>
items:Observable<any[]>
alldata:Observable<any[]>
constructor(public afs:AngularFirestore,db:AngularFirestore) {  }

getitems(){
this.itemscollection=this.afs.collection<any[]>('categories')

return  this.items=this.itemscollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
map(actions=>actions.map(a=>{
  const data=a.payload.doc.data() ;
  const id = a.payload.doc.id;

   return { id, ...data };
  }))
 )

}


adddata(data){
this.datacollection=this.afs.collection<any[]>('data')

this.datacollection.add(data)
 this.alldata=this.datacollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
 map(actions=>actions.map(a=>{
 const alldata=a.payload.doc.data() ;
 const idofdata = a.payload.doc.id;
 return { idofdata, ...alldata };
 }))
 )

 }
 getdata(){
 return this.alldata
}

}
```

admin-new component

//Here i am getting the categories that is in my cloud firestore
Screenshot of data in firestore

**https://ibb.co/nfF1pVv**

```
export class AdminNewComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('f') form:NgForm
categories
default="Bread"

constructor(public iservice:ItemsService,private 
prservice:ProductsService,private router:Router,private 
route:ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.iservice.getitems().subscribe(items=>{
this.categories=items
console.log(this.categories)
})
}
onsubmit(f){

if(this.form.valid){
this.iservice.adddata(f)
}
this.router.navigate(['admin/products'])

}}
```

admin-products

//Here i am getting the error if i try to fetch the data from firestore
  (even if the data already exists) without adding one new data
Screenshot of the data in firestore

**https://ibb.co/dr62vqT**

```
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
subscription:Subscription
categories:any[]=[]
default="Bread"
alldata
constructor(public iservice:ItemsService,private 
prservice:ProductsService,private router:Router,private 
route:ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.subscription=this.prservice.fetchproducts.subscribe(
(data)=>{
this.categories=data
} 
)
this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}

onclick(el){
this.prservice.editchanged.next(el)
this.router.navigate(['admin/products/edit'])

}

onclickfetch(){
console.log('sfshf')
this.iservice.getdata().subscribe(data=>{
this.alldata=data
console.log(this.alldata)
})

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make it simple like this:
In your Service.ts file :

```
getData() {
return this.afs.collection('categories').snapshotChanges();
```

}

And in your Component.ts File :

```
Get(){


 this.service.getData().pipe(map(list => list.map(item => {
  let data = item.payload.doc.data();
  let id = item.payload.doc.id;
  return { id, ...data }
}))).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
 this.search=res;})}
```

in you component.html file:

```
<button (click)="Get() > Get Data From Firestore</button>
```

Populate data in html :

```
<ul *ngFor="let i of search>
   <li>{{i}}</li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Muhammad Abdullah, you can even leave the mapping to your service's method like this:

```
getData() {
   return this.afs.collection('categories').snapshotChanges()
   .pipe(map(list => list.map(item => {
       let data = item.payload.doc.data();
       let id = item.payload.doc.id;
       return { id, ...data }
   })));
}
```

Then on your component just subscribe like this:

this:

```
this.iservice.getdata().subscribe(data=>{
   this.alldata=data
   console.log(this.alldata)
});
```